# How to change the color of a wicket linktree node?

Tags: wicket

We are using wicket LinkTree. Once the tree is constructed and rendered on the page, we can dynamically add new nodes to the tree in our application. When a new node is added, we'd like to show the newly added node with a different color (say red).

One approach we took (but didn't work) is the following. We extend the LinkTree class and override the newNodeComponent method as follows.

```
@Override
protected Component newNodeComponent(String id, IModel<Object> model) {
    return new LinkIconPanel(id, model, TalepTreeForTTBina.this) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4518741854057038753L;

        @Override
        protected void onNodeLinkClicked(Object node, BaseTree tree, AjaxRequestTarget target)
        { . . . . . .
```

Then we add an html attribute (class) to this LinkIconPanel thing. After that, our plan was to write a jquery function to look into that class on the tree, and then change the color of the < td > (or actually the < span >) tag where the text is shown. However, the final markup we get is something like the following:

```
< td class="myClass" . . . .>
  < wicket:panel ....>
    < table . . . >
      < tbody . . . >
        < tr . . . >
          < td . . . >
            < a ...>
              < span > my text that I want to change the color < /span >
```

I have access to the outermost td tag (on the top above) but don't have access to the inner tags from my Java Wicket code. So I'm just inserting myClass to the outermost td tag from the wicket code and hoping to handle the color from the jquery side on the client. It looks like (from my css code) I can't reach to the < table> tag from jquery (or css) since there is a < wicket:panel > tag in between.

So my question is:
1. Is there a better way of changing a color of a LinkTree node?
2. If this is the way I should go, how can I reach to that < span > tag from css? I can't use RenderBodyOnly(true) since I'm not adding the tree nodes manually in my code and I cannot access the node (the item to be added as a node). LinkTree does that for me.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use SimpleAttributeModifier to modify the css in my html markup as follows:

example.css:

```
span.new-yellow { background: #dadada; color: #dddd55 }
```

example.java:

```
SimpleAttributeModifier sam = new SimpleAttributeModifier("class", ".alt-yellow");
if(node.) {
    exampleComponent.add(sam);
}
```

perhaps you can create a model on your node to indicate that it is "new" and add the SimpleAttributeModifier in this case?

Another option could be to use HeaderContributor to do something along the lines of the following:

```
        add(new HeaderContributor(new IHeaderContributor() {
            public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
                response.renderOnLoadJavascript("document.getElementById('" + node.getMarkupId() + "').YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_HERE");
            }
        }));
```

On second thought, that might not be Ajax friendly.  Anyway, just some thoughts.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Override the LinkIconPanel's newContentComponent method. Provide a new Label but override its onComponentTag method, adding the class attribute and a value.

```
@Override
protected Component newContentComponent(String componentId, BaseTree tree,
        IModel<?> model) 
{       
    return new Label(componentId, model)
    {
        @Override
        protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) 
        {
            tag.put("class", "colourMe");
            super.onComponentTag(tag);
        }
    };
}
```

This will add the class attribute to the span tag and render the html like so:

```
< a >
       < span class="colourMe"> my text that I want to change the color < /span >
</ a >
```

No need for jquery, you can just use the class attribute to colour the text.

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. BTW, is there any way to drag and drop the nodes of a Wicket LinkTree from one node to another? Assume the current tree is the following:
[Parent A (Child 1, Child 2)] [Parent B (Child 3)]. Then I want to drag and drop Child 1 from Parent A to Parent B, and the final tree will look like the following: [Parent A (Child 2)] [Parent B (Child 1, Child 3)]

Comment: Hmm i don't know off the top of my head, might be a little fiddly to get working. But that shouldnt stop you from trying :), checkout the jQuery sortable stuff http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/, plus this guy made it work for tables, which u'll need http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/. Plus wiQuery is very good jQuery + Wicket integration http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/. Sorry i couldn't help further, when i get time i might blog a solution and try to get hold of you http://www.david-robson.co.uk/.